# Clear console using C++ with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to make a C++ console application using Xcode 4.1, but I can't find the command for cleaning the screen while the program is executing...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OSX doesn't have "consoles" the way Windows does.  It has *pseudoterminals*, which act like an old-fashioned [glass terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) to the program running "inside" them, and like a bidirectional [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) to the program that set them up.  That outer program can do whatever it likes with the inner program's input and output.  Notable examples of such programs are Terminal.app, which emulates the venerable [VT-100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100), and ssh, which forwards the I/O over a secure channel to its own controlling terminal (which is probably itself a pseudoterminal).  This is all by way of saying that there isn't a method that's guaranteed to work, because maybe the program on the outside of the pseudoterminal doesn't *have* a "screen" that you can meaningfully "clear."  ([Expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/) is a good example of a program like that.)

Having said that, though, if there *is* a screen, these days you can pretty much count on it to respect the VT-100 control codes.  So this should do what you want:

```
std::cout << "\033[2J" << std::flush;
```

If you find that you need even one more control code, though, it's time to hook your program up to [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), which presents a nice friendly API to all the tricks that modern terminal windows are capable of, and will also have your back in the increasingly unlikely event that your program is attached to a terminal (or a program emulating a terminal) that is *not* a VT-100 nor one of its descendants.